# Automatic category assignment upon attachment upload

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets say the media library has the following category [news, events, photo, page, post]

Your wordpress also has the above 5 set as `post-type`. What I want is when

1- `Events` -> `Add New`
2- File is uploaded while adding a new `events` post-type
3- File Finished uploading, wordpress should automatically attach `events` category for that attachment file.

I have code to update the category to a set value after upload, but could not find the currently editing `post-type` when running this function.

**adds category 3 to the uploaded file**

```
 function add_category_automatically($post_ID) {
            wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, array(3) or 'cat_slug_goes_here', 'category', true);
    }
    add_action('add_attachment', 'add_category_automatically');
```

**gets currently editing post-type via ID** (this displays correctly)

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'do_something_152677' );
function do_something_152677() {
    // Global object containing current admin page
    global $pagenow;
    // If current page is post.php and post isset than query for its post type
    if ('post.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post'])) {
        global $new_current_post_type;
        $new_current_post_type = get_post_type( $_GET['post'] );
    }
}
```

When pulling this value into `cat_slug_goes_here` the category does not get updated because the value doesn't match.

Comment: Can't you just use the $post_ID to get the post information (including post_type)?

Comment: @bobdye as said in question, does not display the value of the post_type when used in `add_category_automatically`

Comment: You say "File is uploaded while adding a new events post-type". Is your code doing the uploading?

Comment: @bobdye no the code hooks to the action in wordpress and triggers when a file uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is uploaded when creating the `event` using the "Add Media" function of the editor, then it should be associated with the original post by the time the action hook runs.

You can then:

```
function add_category_automatically($post_ID) {
    $attach = get_post($post_ID);
    if ($attach->post_parent) {
        $cats = get_the_category()($attach->post_parent);
        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
            wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat->slug, 'category', true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('add_attachment', 'add_category_automatically');
```